# Is this cracking after drilling serious?

Tags: walls, drill, crack, curtain-rail

I drilled this hole for a curtain rod. The next day I noticed this crack (and the chip) appear. Is this serious? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: You will get a better answer if you tell us how your wall is constructed. Or if you don't know, tell us when the house was constructed. Three common construction methods: 1) Plaster over lathe. 2) Drywall. 3) Skim coat of plaster over drywall. This looks like #3, or possibly #2 with a patch job from repairing previous holes for curtain rods.

Comment: Where on Earth are you located? Building practices not only change over time, but vary by location as well.

Comment: FWIW, when I look into the holes, it appears to be the same material all the way through.

Answer (score 2):

Those are hairline cracks, and the location is exactly where you'd expect them. They are the normal result of a house settling. When you drilled the holes, you just allowed the stress to be released. Just use some drywall joint compound and paint over it.